# Smartphone alert from Django/Python app

Tags: android, iphone, python, django, smartphone

I am working on a project where I would have a web application built with Django send alerts to my registered users directly on their Smartphone.

For example, let's say that a user has subscribed to the Newsletter, I want his phone to act as he configured it (for example, ringing or shaking) when a Newsletter come in. Then he could open his Smartphone to read the newsletter. After reading it, the user would be prompted a question to know if he wants to post a Comment. If he click yes, his browser opens at the Newsletter page where he can post his comment. If he clicks No, it simply close the Newsletter until a new one come in.

Is there a way to do this from a Web application with Django/Python ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are four ways to handle this:

1. Write your own custom native app for the phone. Your native iPhone app can receive push notifications from your Django app via [the push notification API](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH1-SW1). You native Android app can receive notifications from your Django app via [the cloud-to-device messaging (C2DM) framework](https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/).
2. Write your own web app (HTML + JavaScript) for the phone, using a wrapper app that handles  push notifications/C2DM. [Adobe PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) is one such wrapper app; there are probably others.
3. Send a message via an existing service, such as Twitter or Email, for which the user already has an app.
4. Use a service like [Pushover](https://pushover.net/), which has their own native app that is intended for notifications from web applications such as yours.

Comment: It seems like the native apps would be the best... However, would there be a way to connect my native app to my Django web application to do what I want ?